# Add Items to RecyclerView from other removed RecyclerView item

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

This may sound a bit complicated but what I want is simple!. I have a `RecyclerView` and each item has a delete `Button`. When I press the button in each item, the corresponding item will get removed from `RecyclerView`. and now I want to show these removed items into another `RecyclerView` in another layout!

This is my `RecyclerView` that I remove the items from each `ButtonClick`:

```
 holder.Btn_Remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mFeedList.remove(newPosition);
                    notifyItemRemoved(newPosition);
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(newPosition,mFeedList.size());
                }
            });
```

and now I have Other `RecyclerView` with `DataList`. i want to add each removed item to be added automatically to this new `DataList`.

```
 private void setDataListItems(){
        mDataList.add(new PendingModel("#198" , "Pizza Hut", "Time : 08.00 ","sector 15", currentDateTimeString, OrderStatus.ACTIVE,0.00));

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: are recyclerviews in one activity or two do you want to send data to another activity from your adapter?

Comment: Hi! each recyclerviews are in different activity

Comment: Hi @FajarKhan , I think you need a solution to store the deleted items, like singleton, even sharedpreference.

Comment: Hi, I have resolved the problem by making the dataset public and access it in other recycled view . just before item gets removed, I add data to this dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same to your next `RecyclerView`. You can add the item to your data set and then call `notifyItemInserted` passing the position of the new data.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing both the objects are same ,i.e, object to be added and removed. In that case You can do sonmethinhg like this, call this `setDataListItems(mFeedList.get(newPosition))` before `mFeedList.remove(newPosition);` this line

and change setDataListItems to like this.

```
setDataListItems(PendingModel removedItem){
mDataList.add(removedItem))
adapterOfDataList.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should store deleted Items for your other activity I think the best solution for you would be adding an extra column to your database let's call it status, and set that field to deleted for those that are deleted.

but the alternative is using `SharedPrefrences` like this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

        editor.putString(Name, n);
        editor.putString(Phone, ph);
        editor.putString(Email, e);
        editor.commit();
```

and put the code above in your `removeItem` method in your adapter and afterward get these in your other activity. use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values) for more details.